# How to show remote files with QFileSystemModel? (SSH connection)

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel

I am trying to show remote directories with `QFileSystemModel`. But it shows me root of localhost. Here is my part of code:

```
mFileSystemModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
mFileSystemModel->setReadOnly(true);

mFileSystemModel->setRootPath("st@192.168.4.3:/sql.db");

ui->treeView->setModel(mFileSystemModel);

ui->treeView->setRootIndex(mFileSystemModel->index("st@192.168.4.3:/sql.db"));
```

However in treeView I see root `("/")` of my localhost computer. Could you please help me how I can make ssh and show remote files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it only works for the local file system, but it will work if you can [mount the remote files to your file system](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh).

> The QFileSystemModel class provides a data model for the **local**
>   filesystem.

Comment: I see, so how can I get those files? Do you have any idea?

Comment: As I already said, you must mount them to your local file system https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+connection+mount&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=HFsXV6aLJ4Gb6AS63YWAAw